# ParametricPlot3D/2D won't work and leaves a blank space

Tags: plotting, graphics

I've been trying to evaluate this line

```
ParametricPlot3D[{x, radii[x]*Cos[t], 
  radii[x]*Sin[t] + centers[x][[2]], EdgeForm[]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, {x, 
  lowerx, upperx}, ViewPoint -> {1, -3, .5}, PlotPoints -> {20, 20}, 
 Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> 350, Axes -> False]
```

but nothing comes up, I'm not sure where have I gone wrong 
These are the definitions,

```
upperx = Min[bottommaxx, topmaxx];
lowerx = Max[bottomminx, topminx];
centers[x_] = {x, (top[x] + bottom[x])/2};
radii[x_] = (top[x] - bottom[x])/2;
```

Comment: what are radii, centers, lowerx, upperx ?

Comment: you need to remove `, EdgeForm[]`.

Comment: @Algohi Does that mean I have to input the values in the line? Sorry, first time user :)

Comment: @kguler tried, still does not work

Comment: I think you have definition for them. but we can't help you because simply we cannot run your code. either provide them in your question or use suggestion of kguler and see if it helps.

Comment: Marissa, as Algohi noted if you paste the lines in your notebook where `lowerx, upperx, radii, and centers` are defined, people will be able help more easily. For `ParametricPLot3D` you need to have a 3D input in the first argument; currently you have 2 elements in that list (after removing the erroneous `EdgeForm` piece).

Comment: @kguler I have posted the lines where they are defined, thank you so much, do correct me if im wrong

Comment: Marissa, welcome to Mathematica.SE. Please consider visiting the [tour page](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) on the basic rules of the site, and [editing help page](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) for editing help.

Comment: Marissa, you have introduced more variables and functions without values/definitions -- `bottommaxx, topmaxx, bottomminx, topminx, top, bottom` :)

Comment: @kguler okay I will get back to this and find my way around this labyrinth first, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

In order to get things work I advise you to first check out help page for the function you're planning to use.

Here, lets check out [ParametricPlot3D](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot3D.html). And then look up your code for differences.

```
ParametricPlot3D[{x, radii[x]*Cos[t], 
radii[x]*Sin[t] + centers[x][[2]], EdgeForm[]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, {x, 
lowerx, upperx}, ViewPoint -> {1, -3, .5}, PlotPoints -> {20, 20}, 
Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> 350, Axes -> False]
```

and for parameters in this code:

```
upperx = Min[bottommaxx, topmaxx];
lowerx = Max[bottomminx, topminx];
centers[x_] = {x, (top[x] + bottom[x])/2};
radii[x_] = (top[x] - bottom[x])/2;
```

After comparison you should see that use of `EdgeForm[]`is not right. And a second warning for the parameters. They still are not enough.

A working code should give parameters clearly as follows:

```
radii[x_] := x; centers[x_] := {x, x + 1, x + 2};
lowerx := 5; upperx := 10;

ParametricPlot3D[
 {x, radii[x]*Cos[t], radii[x]*Sin[t] + centers[x][[2]]},
 {t, 0, 2 Pi}, {x, lowerx, upperx},
 ViewPoint -> {1, -3, .5},
 PlotPoints -> {20, 20},
 Boxed -> False,
 ImageSize -> 350,
 Axes -> False]
```

[image]

When you define the functions `bottom[x]` and and `top[x]`and the lists `upperx` and `lowerx` by declaring `bottommaxx`, `topmaxx`, `bottomminx` and `topminx` your code will work as you want.